# Catch the NoSuchElementException from isDisplayed( ) in selenium?

Tags: scala, selenium

I am trying to make a function to catch org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException, and here is my implementation in scala:

```
def doesElementExists() = {    
  try {
    //as long as isDisplayed() returns a boolean value, it means the element exists in the html code
    seleniumElement.isDisplayed()
    true
  } catch {
    case element_not_found_exception: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException => {
      false
    }
  }
}
```

However, as soon as I check for a nonexistent element, which I expect the function to return a false, it blow off and throw back

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException, 
: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"nonexistent-element"};
```

I am wondering why the catch block did not handle the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsDisplayed` is a property of an element that has already been found. What you are doing is essentially this (C# code):

```
var element = driver.FindById("nonexistent-element"); //<---This is what throws NoSuchElementException
try
{
    var displayed = element.IsDisplayed;
}
catch(NoSuchElementException)
{
}
```

So to achieve what you want, your `doesElementExists` function should take in the locator as a parameter, and wrap the try-catch statement around *finding* the element.